# Does an app using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis Nuget package require some additional SDKs/software to be installed on end-user's machine?

Tags: msbuild, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am publishing a Windows Store app which uses .NET Compiler Platform "Roslyn". 
I am using these packages:

```
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" version="2.6.1" targetFramework="net462" developmentDependency="true" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
```

The app is referencing classes like `CSharpSyntaxWalker` and `MSBuildWorkspace`. The app needs to be able to open basically any C# Solution file (.sln) or a C# project file (.csproj).

Does my app require Visual Studio 2017 or some additional SDKs to be installed on end-user's machine? How do I instruct my users to install the additional software if needed? Is it some exact version which is needed and where to download the installer from? For example, is Visual Studio 2015 enough?

From various unofficial sources I have understood that at least MSBuild needs to installed. My current assumption is that the minimum installation requires [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) unless user has already installed VS2017.